# CHtml::listData findall returns last element

Tags: yii

I have a dropdown list. Within the dropdownlist, I use listdata to retrieve the data from another table. But strangely, it only gets the last item in the table.

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'status_id',CHtml::listData(OrderStatus::model()->findAll(),'status_id', 'status'))
```

`chtml::listdata` strangely only shows this `array(1) { [""]=> string(9) "Delivered" }` while in the table there are 7 rows/id, where delivered is the last entry. What happened to the others?

Another odd thing is that `$model->status_id` is actually id 1, so it shouldn't display 'Delivered', it should be showing 'New'.

Comment: What are the field names in the table for `OrderStatus`? Also do you have a `defaultScope()`?

Comment: in status column i have new, processing, shipped, return request, cancelled, refund, delivered. Yes I have `defaultscope()`, but even when i remove it the same problem occurs.

Comment: I meant what are the column names? Is your primary key column `status_id`?

Comment: yes that is the pk. It's going to the right column otherwise 'delievered' wouldn't show up. This is just strange. The only way I can do is to manually type it in the array now (i know, terrible).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

Example 1: Generating a list data for categories

```
    // you can use here any find method you think proper to return your data from db*/

    $models = categories::model()->findAll();

    // format models resulting using listData     
    $list = CHtml::listData($models, 'category_id', 'category_name');    
    print_r($list);
```

HTML Output (Example):

```
    array("1" => "Arts", "2" => "Science", "3" => "Culture");
```

Comment: it's giving me... `Array ( [] => Delivered )`.. and not the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have by any chance a default scope.

Just do a debug of OrderStatus::model()->findAll() and see if it returns 7 records or just 1.

Comment: it returns all 7 when i do a var_dump. Yes I do have a default scope, but I remove it, it's still the same problem.

Comment: can you please paste the result of print_r(OrderStatus::model()->findAll()). Are you sure that you have a column called 'status_id' and it is not only 'id'

Answer (score 0):

Your chtml::listdata strangely showing
 array(1) { [""]=> string(9) "Delivered" }

Is because you must have same entries in status_id column of all the rows in OrderStatus which is blank/null as per above array.

In below call

CHtml::listData(OrderStatus::model()->findAll(),'status_id', 'status')

status_id is key( index of array ) for your generated list array & its getting overwritten by same value everytime, thats whay its showing only one & last value.